# How to set vertex attributes for GraphViz in Racket

Tags: graph, lisp, racket, graphviz

I'm trying to figure out how to use vertex-attributes with racket graphviz ([graph library](https://docs.racket-lang.org/graph)). For example adding some style attributes. Here's what I have so far.

```
#lang racket
(require graph)

(define mygraph (directed-graph '(
                                  (
                                   (a b)
                                   (c d)
                                  )
                                 )))

(define-vertex-property mygraph style #:init "")
(style-set! 'b "filled, bold")

(define graphtext (graphviz mygraph
                            #:vertex-attributes [style 'mygraph]))
```

In the [function definition for graphviz](https://docs.racket-lang.org/graph/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._graph%2Fmain..rkt%29._graphviz%29%29) It says that #:vertex-attributes must be a list of lists and contain a symbol or procedure. But it also implies that you have to use #:vertex-attributes in conjunction with [define-vertex-property](https://docs.racket-lang.org/graph/index.html#%28form._%28%28lib._graph%2Fmain..rkt%29._define-vertex-property%29%29) but I'm not exactly sure how I connect the two.

A couple variations I've tried with no success...

```
(define graphtext (graphviz mygraph
  #:vertex-attributes [style 'b]))

(define graphtext (graphviz mygraph
  #:vertex-attributes [style 'b]))

(define graphtext (graphviz mygraph
  #:vertex-attributes [style (lambda () 'b)]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```lisp
(define graphtext
  (graphviz mygraph
            #:vertex-attributes `([style ,style])))
```

The [graph library tests](https://github.com/stchang/graph/blob/master/graph-test/tests/graph/graphviz.rkt) were helpful in figuring it out.

---

From the documentation you linked, `#:vertex-attributes` associates an attribute name (corresponding to `symbol?` in the contract) with a *vertex property*. The form

```
(define-vertex-property graph prop-name maybe-init maybe-vs)
```

defines a vertex property *prop-name*, which is a procedure (corresponding to `procedure?` in the contract).
`` `([style ,style]) `` associates the attribute name `style` with the vertex property `style`.